# iterate over a particular column in dataframe and return true or false (ie) if i have a digit in my text

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({text_summary: ['my students need 8\ tablets to work on a project', 'My students need 5 tablets for our classroom technology center PLEASE!!!']
```

i want go through each row of the text_summary column and check if there are any digits and return true or false ad create another column in same dataframe with the returned values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) numeric by regex `\d+` and then test by [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text_summary': ['my students need 8\ tablets to work on a project', 
                                    'My students need 5 tablets for 
                                     our classroom technology center PLEASE!!!',
                                    'no digit']})

df['digit'] = df['text_summary'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
df['test'] = df['digit'].str.isdigit().fillna(False)
print (df)

                                        text_summary digit   test
0   my students need 8\ tablets to work on a project     8   True
1  My students need 5 tablets for our classroom t...     5   True
2                                           no digit   NaN  False
```

Another idea is use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['test'] = df['text_summary'].str.contains('\d+')
df['digit'] = df['text_summary'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```